# Keep frequency from formating labels

Tags: r, quanteda

In a text which have formating labels such as

```
data.frame(id = c(1,2), text = c("something here <h1>my text</h1> also <h1>Keep it</h1>", "<h1>title</h1> another here"))
```

How can someone keep the frequency of whatever it is in the

. Exaple of expected output:

```
data.frame(h1label = c("my text", "Keep it", "title"), frq = c(1,1,1))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can remove the tags and get the frequency with `table`

```
table(unlist(strsplit(gsub("\\s*<h1>|</h1>\\s*", ",", df1$text), ",")))
```

Comment: @foc no, it is splitting only at `,`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **quanteda** for this, you can process this via two `char_segment()` calls, one to get the text before `</h1>`, and the second to then just select the text after `<h1>`.  (This could also work on a corpus via `corpus_segment()`.)

Here's how, with your desired output:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.1

df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), text = c("something here <h1>my text</h1> also <h1>Keep it</h1>", "<h1>title</h1> another here"))

df_frq <- df$text %>%
  # corpus(docid_field = "id") %>%
  char_segment("</h1>", pattern_position = "after") %>%
  char_segment("<h1>", pattern_position = "before") %>%
  table() %>%
  data.frame()
names(df_frq) <- c("h1label", "frq")

df_frq
##   h1label frq
## 1 Keep it   1
## 2 my text   1
## 3   title   1
```